# Что означает номер издания у книги?

Tags: книги

Мне нужно прочесть книгу, но я нашел аж три издания. На всех трех книгах, одна и та же обложка, но немного разное название и у каждого издания разный год выпуска. И я не знаю, что мне нужно, из-за того, что не знаю, что означают эти ИЗДАНИЯ. Что такое издания? Первое, второе, третье...?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он 1) и в самом деле не относится к IT (а относится к области "общие знания" (надеюсь, такая есть -))) и 2) очевидно отвечен, уже принес пользу автору вопроса и вряд ли будет востребован кем-то еще.

Comment: Я тоже голосую за закрытие, но перед этим предлагаю наставить автору плюсов!

Comment: Если это Вам важно, то мне не жалко.

Comment: @avp: я же пошутил. Этот вопрос модераторы подняли и меня уведомили. хотел удалить, да нельзя.

Comment: Ну, не отзывать же...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@shatal](/users/14189/shatal), это редакция самого текста, что-то вроде обновления в ПО - закрытие старых ошибок и привнесение дополнений/изменение с учетом современного состояния дел. Чем позднее редакция, тем более современный текст.

Comment: @Etki, Спасибо! Не буду тратить время, ушел читать:)

Answer (score 0):

[[@shata](/users/14189/shatal)](/users/14189/shatal), как Вам уже верно заметил [[@etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), но он забыл упомянуть, что новые редакции, как и ПО, может нести новые ошибки! Вам рекомендовал бы держать несколько книг. Читать, конечно, новую, но если что-то становится непонятным, то обращаться к более ранним издательствам. Дело в том, что любой автор пытается более удачные, на его взгляд, формулировки тех или иных концепций донести до читателя, но бывает так, что ему этого не удается.